# Escaping passwords in Azure Databricks jdbc connection

Tags: python, jdbc, azure-sql-database, azure-databricks

I am trying to pass through a password which has a lot of punctuation in it via widgets in azure databricks. This process gets called from Azure Data Factory which appears to be passing in variables fine.  This is how I pass things in and configure the relevant connection info for later export using SQL code:

```
%python
#Get variables to write to DB

input_sql_conn_string = dbutils.widgets.get("dest_sql_server_url")
input_db_name = dbutils.widgets.get("dest_db_name")
input_dest_username = dbutils.widgets.get("dest_username")
input_dest_password = dbutils.widgets.get("dest_password")
input_dest_table_schema = dbutils.widgets.get("dest_table_schema")
input_dest_table_name = dbutils.widgets.get("dest_table_name")

dest_table_full = input_dest_table_schema + "." + input_dest_table_name

#Configure whole connection string
url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{input_sql_conn_string}:1433;database={input_db_name};user={input_dest_username};password={input_dest_password}"

#Set conf variables so they are accessible by SQL code
spark.conf.set("var.python_sql_url", url)
spark.conf.set("var.python_dest_table", dest_table_full)
spark.conf.set("var.python_username", input_dest_username)
spark.conf.set("var.python_password", input_dest_password)
```

I perform a bunch of SQL tasks which aren't important here then try to export to an Azure SQL table using the passed in information:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW jdbcTable
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  url ${var.python_sql_url},
  dbtable ${var.python_dest_table},
  user ${var.python_username},
  password ${var.python_password}
);

INSERT INTO TABLE jdbcTable
SELECT m.eventId, m.locationId, m.occurredOn, m.sequenceNumber, m.eventType
FROM unified.events.location m
```

I get the following error, indicating a problem in the password string. Seems like the password has a bunch of punctuation marks in it that is stuffing up the SQL loading:

[image]

How do I escape those characters? Or make the password in the string OK to be parsed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh, I figured it out. Leaving here for others if required.  It was actually complaining that single quotes weren't applied to the string properly, so I added them to the JDBC SQL call options:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY VIEW jdbcTable
USING org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc
OPTIONS (
  url '${var.python_sql_url}',
  dbtable '${var.python_dest_table}',
  user '${var.python_username}',
  password '${var.python_password}'
);
```

Note the single quotes before and after each option definition.

All in all though, the code gives a good summary of how to:

1. Create a Notebook in Azure Data Bricks which starts with Python to add input variables
2. Store the variables in conf variables for SQL access later
3. Use SQL Code to extract data directly to an Azure SQL database

I am calling this from Data Factory and adding variables as Base parameters which define which Server/Table I am writing to:
[image]

Other details:
Cluster is set to Shared Access mode, using runtime version 11.3 LTS, giving access to unity catalog.  Notebook is a Python SQL mix (limited to this in Shared Access mode) and is set as SQL as the base language (which is why you see %python at the first line of code in the first cell.